# Yii booster: how to render a cgridview inside a relation table row?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, cgridview

I'm using boostrap library on Yii via yii-booster

I've created a relation table view

The related view is a TbGriView itself

Vhen in a row i click on the link on the 'related' column, the row expands itself, and render a TbGridview inside it.

The problem is that the internal gridview cannot be sorte, paged or filtered, because each action on it causes that the entire container grid will empty

Note
- external grid as a id of 'extenalgrid'
- each internal grid has as id like 'internalgrid-$rowId' , so every internal grid as differnt id on div, table and table row elements.
- the action called from "render related tabel" link is using renderPartial without the postProcess option. If i use potProcess, the row will be empty

So is it not possible to rendere a full working gridview/tbgridview into a related table ?

Comment: Have you tried using different `css` classes for the filters, buttons and headers for the different tables? From the `jquery.yiigridview.js` file events are bound to selectors as `$('#table-id .selector-class')` so elements in your internal gridView still trigger the events bound to the external gridView. You'd also have to specify a different url for the internal gridView by setting it's `ajaxUrl`.

Comment: It's right, make it answer and i'll vote up. thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different `css` classes for the filters, buttons and headers for the different tables. From the `jquery.yiigridview.js` file events are bound to selectors as `$('#table-id .selector-class')` so elements in your internal gridView still trigger the events bound to the external gridView. You also have to specify a different `url` for the internal gridView by setting it's `ajaxUrl`.